# JqxGrid programmatic edit mode resets grid contents

Tags: javascript, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I want to allow inline edit in a JqxGrid (JQWidgets v3.2.2), using my own buttons to switch to and from edit mode.

I figured i'd achieve this by setting these options in the constructor of my jqxgrid:

```
editable: true,
editmode: 'programmatic'
```

However when i do this:

- cells still switch to edit mode on reponse to click events
- calls to `beginrowedit` on the grid results in all editable cells
  contents being cleared and only one cell switching to edit mode.

Here's a fiddle illustrating this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/abenain/VTFAR/.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know to edit a row, the editmode should be   `editmode: 'selectedrow'` Mixing programmatic edit with row editing seems to be not yet supported.

Comment: Accordin to the jqxgrid api, editmode supports several options: 'click', 'selectedcell', 'selectedrow', 'dblclick', 'programmatic'
(see: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-api.htm)

Comment: and according to the same API, 'programmatic' can be used only in combination with the begincelledit and endcelledit, not beginrowedit

Comment: Ok, this might explain the 2nd problem, but still the grid cell shouldn't be switching to edit mode in response to click events

Comment: Substantially, your answer is right: mixing programmatic edit with row editing does not work. Edit your answer and i'll accept it.